# "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png")

Tags: android, cordova

This is the first time I encountered this. The title is displayed in the logcat when I run my phonegap app. Based on experience, it means that my `index.html` can't be found. This is the structure of my `www` folder. [image]

If you need to look at my code, I can put it here. I run my other apps, it will run. Is this an eclipse issue? My project was fine 1 hr ago then when I came back and pressed `RUN` this happened.

Answer (score 0):

super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

Comment: tried that before I posted the question. still won't run

Comment: https://www.robertkehoe.com/2013/01/fix-for-phonegap-connection-to-server-was-unsuccessful/